# Rails 4 A Faster way to list all records in Model

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, performance

I have a Products model with 6,000 records in it (not many). When I run a loop in my view to simply list all records in a table, similar to this..

```
<% Product.all.each do |product|  %>
   <%= product.serial_number %> <br />
<% end %>
```

It takes 13.02 seconds for it to load in my view and show my records in the webpage. This is both in my dev ENV and prod ENV and I tried using a MySQL and sqlite database. Seem to be no difference.

BUT, when I run this query in the rails console it completes in 88.2ms (under 1 second).

What could be holding this up?

Comment: Do you have associations with this model?

Comment: Yes, I have about about 8 actually. 6 of them are belongs_to: and 2 of them are has_many: associations. And now that you're bringing this up, I see a lot of SQL running related to them. Is it looking up every association for every row?

Comment: Yes it is. See my detailed answer bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Joining**

Most importantly you must join the associations that can be joined. Look into your server log and see when you display the page if you have a long list of database fetching. Example if your `Product` is associated to `User` you will see one "SELECT" for your list of product, then hundred of "SELECT" for your users. You may want to use this syntax

```
<% Products.joins(:user).each do |product|  %>
  <%= product.serial_number %> <br />
<% end %>
```

Note that you must adapt to your code (I used `user` as an example), it all depends on your associations. See more in the guides [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

Note that `joins` perform an "INNER JOIN", and will remove all records that have nil reference. If it is your case you can use the "Eager loading" technique by using `includes`:

```
Products.includes(:user).each do |product|
```

**Find_each**

Optionally, try using `find_each` which will proceed your records by batches to save so server power. See more details about it in the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches)

```
Products.find_each do |product|
```

**Caching**

Optionally, you can use [caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) to improve performances

```
Products.find_each do |product|
  cache product do
    ...
  end
end
```

**Pagination**

And also consider using pagination, if possible, to restrict the number of records fetch from the database

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. When I add the <% cache product %> and <% end %> tags, I get the following error: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Comment: My bad, I forgot the `do` (edited my answer). Anyhow I guess you can directly jump to the "joining" chapter, because as per your last comment it seems to be the main reason of your slow query

Comment: Thanks the clarity. With adding all columns to be shown my query took about 32 seconds in the view. Adding this improved to about 11, which is great. But is that still a long time for 6000 records? I always thought rails was powerful enough to load this few records in only a couple seconds at most.

Comment: Hard to tell, many elements can impact speed, such as correct indexing of your database records, speed of your caching back-end, etc... Google should provide some useful informations for your case

Answer (score 2):

You're after a single field? Use [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck). That's exactly what its for.

```
<% Products.pluck(:serial_number).each do |serial_number| %>
   <%= serial_number %> <br />
<% end %>
```

This both generates more efficient SQL (a `select serial_number` instead of `select *`) and bypasses the step of instantiating ActiveRecord objects for every returned result, only so that you can access a single property of that model.

> BUT, when I run this query in the rails console it completes in 88.2ms (under 1 second).

Unless you actually begin iterating over the results, Rails won't *do* anything. Rails only actually instantiates records when you attempt to access the results.

---

**Re: Your comment**

> However I was actually just showing the above as a example. I'm actually displaying all fields for each record. Any tricks for this?

Then, you shouldn't be using a loop, as your sample indicates. Use partials, and [collection rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections), which is *much* faster than iterating over the results yourself.

Create a view called `app/views/products/_product.html.erb`, and put the "body" of the loop in that file. It might look something like this:

```
<div class="product">
  Name: <%= link_to product, product.name %><br/>
  Serial Number: <%= product.serial_number %>
</div>
```

Then, in the top-level view, render the entire collection using that parial:

```
render partial: 'product', collection: Product.all
```

Comment: I'm getting this: undefined local variable or method `product' for #<#<Class:0x00000110099668>:0x00000109060d10>

Comment: Depends on what your model is named.

Comment: It's a products model hmmmm

Comment: You should never have a model named "Products". It should be "Product". This is an extremely important contention in Rails, and you should adhere to it unless you have an extremely good reason for not dong so.

Comment: Sorry it is indeed Product.rb model